# How do I edit a powershell psd1 file passed in as an argument?

Tags: powershell

I have a function that takes a powershell psd1 file as argument

```
function Transform-DataFile

[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([int])]
Param
(
    # Param1 help description
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               Position=0)]
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.ArgumentToConfigurationDataTransformation()]
    $DataFile,


    [String]
    $OutFile
)

Begin
{
}
Process
{

    $DataFile.NodeName = "Kalle"

    Set-Content -Path $OutFile -Value $DataFile
}
End
{
}
```

I want to edit this file and then save it with another filename. The result file should be a valid powershell psd1 file. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: *"I want to edit this file and then save it with another filename."* What have you tried so far to achieve this? What doesn't work as expected? As it stands your question is too broad and would boil down to us writing the function for you. Which is not likely to happen.

Comment: Hi! Sorry this is my first post here. Thank you for your comment. I'll try to edit my question. I don't want any one to write the function for me be rather be guided in the right direction.